# garchFit function in R: Multivariate data inputs require lhs for the formula

Tags: r, time-series

```
df=structure(list(X.1 = 1:10, X = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), json_data.time.updated = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Jan 19, 2019 15:18:00 UTC", 
"Jan 19, 2019 15:19:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 15:51:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 15:52:00 UTC", 
"Jan 19, 2019 15:54:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 15:55:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 15:57:00 UTC", 
"Jan 19, 2019 15:58:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:00:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:01:00 UTC"
), class = "factor"), json_data.time.updatedISO = structure(1:10, .Label = c("2019-01-19T15:18:00+00:00", 
"2019-01-19T15:19:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T15:51:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T15:52:00+00:00", 
"2019-01-19T15:54:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T15:55:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T15:57:00+00:00", 
"2019-01-19T15:58:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:00:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:01:00+00:00"
), class = "factor"), json_data.time.updateduk = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Jan 19, 2019 at 15:18 GMT", 
"Jan 19, 2019 at 15:19 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:51 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:52 GMT", 
"Jan 19, 2019 at 15:54 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:55 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:57 GMT", 
"Jan 19, 2019 at 15:58 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:00 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:01 GMT"
), class = "factor"), code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "USD", class = "factor"), rate = structure(c(6L, 
7L, 10L, 5L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("3,734.2833", 
"3,734.4950", "3,734.9117", "3,734.9600", "3,735.3200", "3,735.7750", 
"3,735.9150", "3,736.0750", "3,736.7717", "3,736.9100"), class = "factor"), 
    description = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "United States Dollar", class = "factor"), 
    rate_float = c(3735.775, 3735.915, 3736.91, 3735.32, 3736.7717, 
    3736.075, 3734.96, 3734.9117, 3734.2833, 3734.495)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

i want perform GARCH model
i try use simple example from help of this library

```
library("fGarch")
b=garchFit(formula = ~ garch(1, 1), data = df, 
         init.rec = c("mci", "uev"), 
         delta = 2, skew = 1, shape = 4, 
         cond.dist = c("norm", "snorm", "ged", "sged", "std", "sstd", 
                       "snig", "QMLE"), 
         include.mean = TRUE, include.delta = NULL, include.skew = NULL, 
         include.shape = NULL, leverage = NULL, trace = TRUE, 

         algorithm = c("nlminb", "lbfgsb", "nlminb+nm", "lbfgsb+nm"), 
         hessian = c("ropt"), control = list(), 
         title = NULL, description = NULL)

garchKappa(cond.dist = c("norm", "ged", "std", "snorm", "sged", "sstd",
                         "snig"), gamma = 0, delta = 2, skew = NA, shape = NA)

summary(b)

Then i get the error
Error in garchFit(formula = ~garch(1, 1), data = df, init.rec = c("mci",  : 
  Multivariate data inputs require lhs for the formula.
```

This time series formed by minites
date variable is json_data.time.updatedISO
metric variable is price rate_float

What does mean this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified `data = df`, where `df` has multiple columns, while the model is just `~ garch(1, 1)`, so there is no way to know which of the variables is supposed to follow this GARCH(1,1). Hence, the errors says that then you need to specify the left hand side. For instance, using

```
formula = rate_float ~ garch(1, 1), data = df
```

does the job and also

```
formula = ~ garch(1, 1), data = df$rate_float
```

as there is no ambiguity in those cases.

Now with your example data `summary(b)` will throw some warnings but that's only due to very few observations; not enough to compute the `Standardised Residuals Tests` part.

Comment: can you answer on two question. When i work not with small data, but with all files from C:/MyFolder. i get the error, i edit post, please check. Second, how can i do forecat with GARCH on 5 minutes ahead?. On small data, your answer works, so i acccept it, but nned help into all data and forecast

Comment: @cbool, please remove that update from your question as it substantially differs from your initial question. However, I think that your data has two NA values, so instead using `na.omit(df$rate_float)` as data should help. Forecasting is even more unrelated so please post a new question with a _clear_ reproducible example and expected output.

Comment: i did it and asked new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54278313/forecasting-using-garch-model-in-r