# Forecasting using GARCH model in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series

```
df=structure(list(X = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    json_data.time.updated = structure(1:41, .Label = c("Jan 19, 2019 15:18:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 15:19:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 15:51:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 15:52:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 15:54:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 15:55:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 15:57:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 15:58:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:00:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:01:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:03:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:04:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:06:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:07:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:09:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:10:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:12:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:13:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:15:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:16:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:18:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:19:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:21:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:22:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:24:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:25:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:27:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:28:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:30:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:31:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:33:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:34:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:36:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:37:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:39:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:40:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:42:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:43:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:45:00 UTC", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 16:46:00 UTC", "Jan 19, 2019 16:48:00 UTC"), class = "factor"), 
    json_data.time.updatedISO = structure(1:41, .Label = c("2019-01-19T15:18:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T15:19:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T15:51:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T15:52:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T15:54:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T15:55:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T15:57:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T15:58:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:00:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:01:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:03:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:04:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:06:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:07:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:09:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:10:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:12:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:13:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:15:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:16:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:18:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:19:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:21:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:22:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:24:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:25:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:27:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:28:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:30:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:31:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:33:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:34:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:36:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:37:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:39:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:40:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:42:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:43:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:45:00+00:00", 
    "2019-01-19T16:46:00+00:00", "2019-01-19T16:48:00+00:00"), class = "factor"), 
    json_data.time.updateduk = structure(1:41, .Label = c("Jan 19, 2019 at 15:18 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:19 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:51 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:52 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:54 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:55 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:57 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 15:58 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:00 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:01 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:03 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:04 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:06 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:07 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:09 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:10 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:12 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:13 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:15 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:16 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:18 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:19 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:21 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:22 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:24 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:25 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:27 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:28 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:30 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:31 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:33 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:34 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:36 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:37 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:39 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:40 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:42 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:43 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:45 GMT", 
    "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:46 GMT", "Jan 19, 2019 at 16:48 GMT"), class = "factor"), 
    code = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = "USD", class = "factor"), rate = structure(1:41, .Label = c("3,735.7750", 
    "3,735.9150", "3,736.9100", "3,735.3200", "3,736.7717", "3,736.0750", 
    "3,734.9600", "3,734.9117", "3,734.2833", "3,734.4950", "3,735.8533", 
    "3,736.1917", "3,735.5450", "3,735.5867", "3,736.0617", "3,736.3417", 
    "3,737.0633", "3,736.9583", "3,737.1667", "3,737.1433", "3,737.0583", 
    "3,736.9283", "3,737.6383", "3,737.5167", "3,737.9133", "3,738.7533", 
    "3,738.6767", "3,738.5767", "3,738.5917", "3,738.8867", "3,739.6333", 
    "3,739.9600", "3,739.3383", "3,739.9267", "3,739.3067", "3,739.5867", 
    "3,739.6567", "3,739.4267", "3,739.1500", "3,739.8817", "3,739.5550"
    ), class = "factor"), description = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "United States Dollar", class = "factor"), 
    rate_float = structure(1:41, .Label = c("3735.775", "3735.915", 
    "3736.91", "3735.32", "3736.7717", "3736.075", "3734.96", 
    "3734.9117", "3734.2833", "3734.495", "3735.8533", "3736.1917", 
    "3735.545", "3735.5867", "3736.0617", "3736.3417", "3737.0633", 
    "3736.9583", "3737.1667", "3737.1433", "3737.0583", "3736.9283", 
    "3737.6383", "3737.5167", "3737.9133", "3738.7533", "3738.6767", 
    "3738.5767", "3738.5917", "3738.8867", "3739.6333", "3739.96", 
    "3739.3383", "3739.9267", "3739.3067", "3739.5867", "3739.6567", 
    "3739.4267", "3739.15", "3739.8817", "3739.555"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
41L), class = "data.frame")
```

i want perform GARCH model, So i have this code

```
df$rate_float=as.numeric(df$rate_float)
library("fGarch")
b=garchFit(formula = ~ garch(1, 1), data = df$rate_float, 
         init.rec = c( "mci","uev"), 
         delta = 2, skew = 1, shape = 4, 
         cond.dist = c("norm", "snorm", "ged", "sged", "std", "sstd", 
                       "snig", "QMLE"), 
         include.mean = TRUE, include.delta = NULL, include.skew = NULL, 
         include.shape = NULL, leverage = NULL, trace = TRUE, 

         algorithm = c("nlminb", "lbfgsb", "nlminb+nm", "lbfgsb+nm"), 
         hessian = c("ropt"), control = list(), 
         title = NULL, description = NULL)

garchKappa(cond.dist = c("norm", "ged", "std", "snorm", "sged", "sstd",
                         "snig"), gamma = 0, delta = 2, skew = NA, shape = NA)
```

So time variable is json_data.time.updateduk.
How can i create forecast on 10 minutes ahead?
Second, but related question , how can i get forecast for initial values to understand quality of forecast
so as output i need
1. forecast on 10 minutes ahead like this
[image]

2. Residuals
   I.E. something like this
   [image]

How to do it?

Comment: Things like "10 minutes ahead" are complicated since your time series is irregularly spaced. Even estimating this simple model can be seen to be incorrect. In particular, with your model we cannot forecast a given number of minutes ahead. It's about the number of steps/observations ahead. So, what would your question then be?

Comment: @JuliusVainora, it is test data. So if even estimating  will wrong it is not scary. but in simple terms, if it can't be, then the data should be predicted for 10  observations ahead

Comment: or i can change data , that it be regular, to create forecast on 10 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may forecast 10 steps ahead with

```
predict(b, n.ahead = 10)
#    meanForecast meanError standardDeviation
# 1      20.19952  20.82351          20.82351
# 2      20.19952  20.84651          20.84651
# 3      20.19952  20.86948          20.86948
# 4      20.19952  20.89243          20.89243
# 5      20.19952  20.91535          20.91535
# 6      20.19952  20.93825          20.93825
# 7      20.19952  20.96112          20.96112
# 8      20.19952  20.98396          20.98396
# 9      20.19952  21.00679          21.00679
# 10     20.19952  21.02959          21.02959
```

while the fitted values are given by

```
fitted(b)
#        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
# 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 
#       11       12       13       14       15       16       17       18       19       20 
# 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 
#       21       22       23       24       25       26       27       28       29       30 
# 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 
#       31       32       33       34       35       36       37       38       39       40 
# 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 20.19952 
#       41 
# 20.19952
```

Mean forecast and fitted values are constant since you are modelling the conditional variance; for this reason the other two columns of the forecasts are nonconstant. Fitted conditional standard deviations are given by

```
b@sigma.t
#  [1] 11.8995423 19.2244571 18.2258257 17.2273530 16.2290683 15.2310087 14.2332215 13.2357682
#  [9] 12.2387307 11.2422194 10.2463878  9.2514556  8.2577478  7.2657667  6.2763312  5.2908696
# [17]  4.3121073  3.3459283  2.4075307  1.5482802  0.9990692  1.2645580  2.0494083  2.9666550
# [25]  3.9245394  4.8992833  5.8825118  6.8705831  7.8616716  8.8547641  9.8492545 10.8447583
# [33] 11.8410198 12.8378627 13.8351612 14.8328235 15.8307808 16.8289806 17.8273822 18.8259534
# [41] 19.8246687
```

Comment: thank you. Why predict(b, n.ahead = 10) has same value. Whats role does have sigma.t

Comment: @cbool, mean forecasts are the same since the model is for conditional variance (and fitted values for it are given by `b@sigma.t`), not the level. I suggest first to familiarize yourself with GARCH models before jumping straight to estimation, because certain ideas here are very different. See, e.g., [here](https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/ch18-garch.pdf) or [here](http://economia.unipv.it/pagp/pagine_personali/erossi/note32004a.pdf).

Comment: so we modelling the conditional variance. Okey, But can we predict rate_float. I want to know  what will be the dollar exchange rate to bitcoin in 10 steps ahead and not conditional variance. Or it is another question?

Comment: @cbool, modelling conditional variance means modelling errors. Currently that's all you are modelling. You could indeed combine modelling the level of your time series (with, say, AR process) and errors with GARCH. The point of including GARCH is for inferences, better confidence intervals, not accuracy.. Sounds like you need a different model. I may be wrong about something as I haven't used GARCH for a long time, but it should be like this. A sort of analogue that you may want is simply ARMA models.

Comment: @cbool, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/155014/10172) and, more generally, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garch+forecasting).

Comment: some thing i have read, and try use ARMA. Can you help me here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388011/error-in-usemethodpredict-no-applicable-method-for-predict-applied-to-an