# Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('uGARCHfit', 'GARCHfit', 'rGARCH')" in R

Tags: r, time-series

I dynamically   get financial data via API of "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json" for this i use this script

```
library("rjson")
json_file <- "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json"

numOfTimes <- 2L # how many times to run in total
sleepTime <- 60L  # time to wait between iterations (in seconds)
iteration <- 0L
while (iteration < numOfTimes) {
  # gather data
  json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
  # get json content as data.frame
  x = data.frame(json_data$time$updated,json_data$time$updatedISO,json_data$time$updateduk,json_data$bpi$USD)
  # create file to save in 'C:/Myfolder' 
  # alternatively, create just one .csv file and update it in each iteration
  nameToSave <- nameToSave <- paste('C:/Myfolder/', 
                                    gsub('\\D','',format(Sys.time(),'%F%T')), 
                                    'json_data.csv', sep = '_')
  # save the file
  write.csv(x, nameToSave)
  # update counter and wait 
  iteration <- iteration + 1L
  Sys.sleep(sleepTime)
}
```

this script run by cmd file every minute by scheduler in Win8.1

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\x64\Rcmd.exe" BATCH "E:\Rdev\bitcoin.R"
```

Thus folder with csv  dynamically updated by new coming csv.

Suppose i created GARCH-ARMA model

```
require(rugarch)


#We can then compute the ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) model as an example:



  spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", 
                                           garchOrder = c(1, 1), 
                                           submodel = NULL, 
                                           external.regressors = NULL, 
                                           variance.targeting = FALSE), 

                     mean.model     = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1), 
                                           external.regressors = NULL, 
                                           distribution.model = "norm", 
                                           start.pars = list(), 
                                           fixed.pars = list()))

garch <- ugarchfit(spec = spec, data = df$rate_float, solver.control = list(trace=0))
```

now when i do so

```
predict(garch, n.ahead = 5)
```

i get the error

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('uGARCHfit', 'GARCHfit', 'rGARCH')"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are simply using a wrong function. Try instead

```
ugarchforecast(garch, n.ahead = 5)
```

Comment: Also, package `rugarch` uses S4 classes, `predict` S3 ones.

Comment: @Julius Vainora,  I will run the forecast script every 5 minutes from this line of spec <- ugarchspec (variance.model = list (model = "sGARCH",
for example, the script was launched at 17:30, the forecast was made by 5 steps, then it was launched in 1735, the forecast was made by 5 steps, then at 17:40 and so on. How to add predictions  to one csv with date mark(l edited output in post)? Or i should ask new question.

Comment: @cbool, it's a little hard to follow this part of your initial question, but it sounds like you simply can keep loading the csv file, rbinding the new forecasts and saving it again, no? If it doesn't help, then yes, you could post a new question, but make sure that the code there is minimal. E.g., there was no point in adding `garch@fit$sigma` to this question.

Comment: @Julius Vainora , a liitle bit no, i created new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54399787/save-forecast-result-in-csv-file-in-r